# Find the package name of the app playing or using Bluetooth music stream

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, a2dp

How to get to know which app is playing/using music stream. I am able to receive callback through broadcast receiver [BluetoothA2dp](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothA2dp.html) when audio is played or paused/stopped on Bluetooth device and name of broadcast is given below:

```
android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED
```

For eg. when I play music on Bluetooth device through YouTube or Video Player I received callback  `BluetoothA2dp.STATE_PLAYING`  in action - `BluetoothA2dp.ACTION_PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED`
but I am not able to get YouTube or Video Player app package name.

I received callback through broadcast receiver [BluetoothHeadset](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.html#STATE_AUDIO_CONNECTED) when there is incoming or outgoing call on Bluetooth device and name of broadcast receiver is given below:

```
android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
```

Is there any way to get to know the name of package which is playing music on Bluetooth device or how to get the package which has invoked broadcast receiver through intent or context of receiver.

Answer (score 0):

1. User must connect mobile to Bluetooth device
2. Now whenever user play music on mobile through any app like saavn, gaana or any other music app, music would be stream/play on Bluetooth device
3. Now broadcast receiver will be called which is registered by action **BluetoothA2dp.ACTION_PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED** = “android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED”
4. In **ACTION_PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED** we get the extra state of intent through BluetoothA2dp.EXTRA_STATE
5. From the extra state, we check whatever music is playing or stop through **BluetoothA2dp.STATE_PLAYING** & **BluetoothA2dp.STATE_NOT_PLAYING**
6. If music is playing, then we check what application/package is currently playing music by class MediaSessionManager for example if Saavn, Ganna music apps are playing then we will get “com.saavn.android”, “com.gaana”
7. We need to pass intent of receiver into manager.getActiveSessions method and we will get List of MediaController
8. From the list of MediaController, we can get package name of applications which are playing music and the top name of the list is the name of the package which is currently playing music for example if Saavn music app is playing on top then we will get “com.saavn.android”